# Matlab 2013a cannot find library powerlib

Tags: windows-8, matlab

I have installed matlab 2013a in my computer. Everything works fine. But when I typed in powerlib in prompt it says cannot find library. Can anyone say how to install this library manually?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [answer given by @Jonas on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3961964/983722).

As [@Edric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957073/failed-to-find-library-powerlib-matlab-simulink-program-executing/3957331#3957331) mentioned, `powerlib` is built into SimPowerSystems. The error you see can thus have two causes

(1) There is no installation of SimPowerSystems in your copy of Matlab. Type `ver` at the command prompt to check for what toolboxes you have installed. If SimPowerSystems doesn't show up in the list, you will have to get the toolbox, otherwise you won't be able to run the model.

(2) Your installation of SimPowerSystems is somehow corrupt. This has never happened to me in Matlab so far, but with modern technology, anything is possible. A fresh install should solve this.